# Add a new NSImageRep to the system-wide Mac OS X save dialog

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsimage

For the Cocoa wizards out there: is it possible to create an NSImageRep "filter service" that registers system-wide and appears as a file type in all "Save" and "Save All" dialogs for images?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Have any possible output (RTF text, plain text, PDF, jpeg, etc.) from any possible app be turned into your magic NSImageRep type and saved as a file?

Comment: Sort of. I just need to create a new image representation accessible to graphics-related software (Preview, Photoshop, etc)